# Как c помощью редактора vim удалить строки с 1001 по 2000 в файле с 10000-ми строк?

Tags: vim, vi

Как c помощью редактора `vim` удалить строки с 1001 по 2000 в файле с 10000-ми строк? Команда `:d999d` приводит к ошибке `E488: Trailing characters`

Comment: Заработало, раскладку клавиатуры нужно - оказывается учитывать :)

Comment: вы, как автор, можете удалить вопрос.

Comment: Не понимаю что хотят о меня Требуя правки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Команды `dd` и `d<количество>d` выполняются без `:`

Команде `:d` можно задать диапазон строк, тогда ваша задача решается так:

```
:1001,2000d
```

Comment: Жалко, что мало кто читает начальные обучалки, идущие чо всеми свободными *nix редакторами. После vim стоить глянуть sed стримовый редактор, палочка-выручалочка любого уважающего себя юниксоид.

Answer (score 3):

Перед большинством команд можно ввести число, означающее сколько раз выполнится команда.

Тогда очевидный (и требующий минимальных познаний в vi) способ:

- встать в начало файла
- набрать 1000 и сразу "стрелка вниз"
- набрать 999dd

Все, можно сохранять файл.

Comment: надо же, никогда не приходило в голову нажать 1000 стрелка вниз. Всегда жал 1000 j

Comment: @AK, всегда жал `1000gg`.